# Using PIPE in python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I am trying to convert some code I have into python. The current code is in a gnu Makefile. I am having some trouble with this line.

```
cat $$dir/cpr/work/$(DATE)/output/XmlOutTxt*/part-r-000* | ./verify_testgen.py
```

What I have done is:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["cat", directory+"cpr/work/"+DATE+"/output/XmlOutTxt*/part-r-000*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["./verify_testgen.py"],stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Im wondering if there is a better way to go about this because I am still running into some issues.

Comment: What issues? Are you seeing error messages? Getting unexpected behavior?

Comment: I would just glob all the files in the output directory and feed them into the `stdin` of the `verify_testgen.py` process.  No reason to create a `cat` subprocess.

Comment: Why not having a look at [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/), instead of a pure Python script replacement?